# Can a workflow determine if a Lookup field has changed?

Tags: workflow

I would like to define a workflow whose rule criteria is that a Lookup field changed, but ISCHANGED and PRIORVALUE generate syntax errors. Both generate the message

> Error: Function (PRIORVALUE|ISCHANGED) may not be used in this type of formula

Is it possible for a workflow to determine when a Lookup has changed or is the Trigger territory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Priorvalue and ischanged are allowed if the workflow type is "any time a record is created or edited". If you change to that it should be allowed.

From [Salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US#PRIORVALUE):

> This function is available only in:
>
> - Assignment rules
> - Validation rules
> - Field updates
> - Workflow rules **if the evaluation criteria is set to Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited.**

Comment: I did not see that in the documentation; thank you!