# Workflow rule to be fired when lookup field is updated?

Tags: workflow, lookup

I have a lookup field X and I want to make a workflow rule to fire when that lookup field is updated or the record is created. How can I do this because I keep getting an error like "Function ischanged cannot be used in this type of field."

Comment: see this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3430/can-a-workflow-determine-if-a-lookup-field-has-changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process builder to capture this functionality. You can set the criteria like this:

Criteria Name like Lookup value changed

Criteria for Executing Actions - Conditions are met

Set Conditions:
Field is Lookup field,
Operator = "Is Changed",
Type = Boolean,
Value = True

Conditions:

All conditions are met.

Now, you can do the action on next step (take the action out from your workflow rule and put those over here).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select

```
created, and every time it's edited
```

and NOT

```
created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria
```

rule itself is very simple

```
ischanged(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want lookup field is updated and workflow fire,for this you will use ISCHANGED function and It will work when you select Evaluation Criteria as Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited.
[image]

[image]

[image]